# How to select columns based on their properties?

Tags: r, dataframe, tidyverse, data-wrangling

I have a data frame with the following three values: 0, 1, and ?. The 0s and 1s are characters and not numeric data. I am trying to subset the data frame to remove the following:

1. All columns that are uniformly 0 or 1
2. All columns that have at least one ?

So the dataset should no invariant columns or columns with missing values.

Here is an illustration of the data frame:

```
   c1 c2 c3 c4 c5 c6 c7 c8 c9 c10
r1 0  1  0  1  ?  ?  ?  ?  0  1
r2 0  1  0  1  1  0  ?  ?  0  1
r3 0  1  0  1  1  0  0  1  1  0
r4 0  1  0  1  1  0  0  1  1  0
r5 0  1  0  1  1  0  0  1  ?  1
r6 0  1  0  1  1  0  0  1  ?  0
r7 0  1  1  0  1  0  0  1  0  0
```

So I want to exclude c1, c2, c5, c6, c7, c8, and c9. How do I do this in base R or tidyverse?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In tidyverse:

```r
df %>% select_if(~!any(.x == '?') & !all(.x == 1) & !all(.x == 0))
   c3 c4 c10
r1  0  1   1
r2  0  1   1
r3  0  1   0
r4  0  1   0
r5  0  1   1
r6  0  1   0
r7  1  0   0
```

Comment: Alternative writing with the non-superseded `where`: `df %>% 
  select(where(~ !(all(.x == "0") | all(.x == "1") | any(.x == "?"))))`

Answer (score 2):

```
> sapply(df,is.integer) & colMeans(df==0)<1 & colMeans(df==1)<1
   c1    c2    c3    c4    c5    c6    c7    c8    c9   c10 
FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
```